# How to modify default spring boot not found url exception with custom message

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exceptionhandler

I'm trying to modify the default error message and status code for all non supported rest end points.

How to do it ?

My Customer error message

```
public class ApiErrorResponse {

    private int code;
    private String message;

    public ApiErrorResponse(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Custom error handling logic:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({NoHandlerFoundException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ApiErrorResponse> handleNoHandlerFoundException(
            NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        ApiErrorResponse apiErrorResponse = new ApiErrorResponse(404, "Resource not found");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(apiErrorResponse);
    }
}
```

and now tried like curl --location 'localhost:8080/some/invalid/url'
But it gives default 404 status code and error message. not custom message . What I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to identify which default error method we need to override, `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java` base class and identify the method to override.
Here `NoHandlerFoundException`and `handleNoHandlerFoundException()` need to be overridden.
above code properly overridden. please add `@EnableWebMvc` in the application.java or @configuration class to identify override methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this line

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

to your application.properties and add `@EnableWebMvc` in your configuration bean